# ReactJS: re-base helper filer for collection method calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6

I have struggled a lot trying to figure out how to combine `ReactJS` and `firebase` (3).

Luckily I found the awesome re-base repo, which is awesome and exactly what I want.

> fb-config.js

```
var Rebase = require('re-base');
var base = Rebase.createClass({
      apiKey: "apiKey",
      authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});
export default base;
```

> app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import base from 'fb-config';
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent';

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
  super();
    // getInitialState
    this.state = {
      DB: {}
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.ref = base.syncState('demo',
  { context: this,
    state: 'DB' }
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  base.removeBinding(this.ref);
}

render() {
  return (
    <ExampleComponent />
  )
}

}

export default App
```

> components/ExampleComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import base from '../fb-config';

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);

    this.pushing = this.pushing.bind(this);
  }

  pushing() {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    let data = {};
    data[now.toString(16)] = 'Hello World';

    base.fetch('demo', {
      context: this, 
      asArray: false
    }).then( snapshot => {
      data = {... snapshot, ...data};
      base.post('demo', {data})
      .then( () = { console.log("pushed") });

    });
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.pushing}>PUSH</button>
    )
  }

};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

This setup works. But I would like to move the pushing method to another file (like `fb-commands.js`). How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move `pushing` as-is, all you need is to pass `context` to the function, since it wont have access to the component instance via `this`.

```
// fb-commands.js
export const pushing = (context) => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    let data = {};
    data[now.toString(16)] = 'Hello World';

    base.fetch('demo', {
         context: context, 
         asArray: false
    }).then( snapshot => {
        data = {... snapshot, ...data};
        base.post('demo', {data})
       .then(() => console.log("pushed"));
    });
};

// components/ExampleComponent.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import base from '../fb-config';
import {pushing} from 'path/to/fb-commands';

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={() => pushing(this)}>PUSH</button>
        );
    }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Comment: This might be a newbie question, but why don't I have to do something with `context` in the arrow function? How does it automatically become equal to `this`?

Comment: In your example, `pushing` is bound to the react component instance, so that inside `pushing` `this` refers to the component instance. In my example, instead of binding `pushing` to the react component instance (which you still _could_ do* btw, but it would be a bit less logical) I pass a reference to the react component instance as first parameter. In both cases, the `context` property on the object passed to `base.fetch(...)` refers to the react component instance. ((*) If you want to bind the `this` of a function, it cannot be an arrow function like I have used.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, I can think of 3 approaches (maybe there are more).

## Approach #1: Via ES6 Import / Export (Simple)

ArneHugo describes it well in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774816/1333836).

Just **export** `pushing` function to a module and then **import** it and use it directly. Pass the `this` context or any other params needed.

Sounds awesome to me if you want to share utility functions.

---

## Approach #2: Via Mixins.

That's not a good practice.

Plus, mixins are not supported when using React components written in ES6 syntax. Moreover, they will not have support for ES6 classes in React. The reason is that they are [considered harmful](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html).

So, mixins are on their way out.

---

## Approach #3: Via Composition (Advanced)

That is the best option if you need to implement something more advanced then just re-using common methods. Let's say if you want:

- to reuse logic and bootstrap abstraction
- to render Highjacking
- to do State abstraction and manipulation
- to do Props manipulation

Then, enter Composition and **Higher-Order Components**!

A higher-order component is just a function that takes an existing component and returns another component that wraps it.

You can use this approach to wrap the component and not only share common code / logic, but share data, manipulate state, props and etc.

More on this topic you can read on the [franleplant's great post here](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.ut7fa8pxw).

---

## Conclusion

- If you need just a helper method abstraction - use Approach #1.
- Never use Approach #2.
- If you want something more then that - consider applying Approach #3.